# how can change dimension of windows page using trackbar in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I know how to display dimension but how can I control it by a trackbar

```
`function displaywindownInner() {
    var W = window.innerWidth;
    var H = window.innerHeight;
    var x = document.getElementById("show");
 

    x.innerHTML = "width:" + W + "Height:" + H+".";
  
}`
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo ..? See also the notes at the end of the article.

Comment: controlling he size oof the window is really restricted in modern browsers.